# ActiveAdmin Logout Link Not Visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

hi I am using active admin gem in my project

I cannot see logout link on active admin dashboard.

I have only one table for all users that is users table

routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do

      ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
      devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' , :registrations => "registrations" }
      namespace :api do
        namespace :v1 do
          resources :users
        end
      end

      resources :users
      devise_scope :user do 
        match '/users/sign_in', to: 'sessions#create', via: :post
        #registration seems to much cooler for authenticable and other stuff
        #match 'api/v1/users' , to: 'registrations#create' , via: :post
      end

    end
```

in /admin/dashboard

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
    div class: "blank_slate_container", id: "dashboard_default_message" do
      span class: "blank_slate" do
        span I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.welcome")
        small I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.call_to_action")
      end
    end
  end # content
end
```

and this how my admin/users look like

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  #permit_params :email , :role_ids ,:password
  permit_params :email , :password ,:role_ids => []

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Users" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :roles, as: :select, multiple: false, collection: Role.all

    end
    f.actions

  end 

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :email
      row :encrypted_password
      row :reset_password_token
      row :reset_password_sent_at
      row :remember_created_at
      row :sign_in_count
      row :current_sign_in_at
      row :last_sign_in_at
      row :current_sign_in_ip
      row :last_sign_in_ip
      row :created_at
      row :updated_at
      row :authentication_token
      row :roles do | user |
        user.roles.first.name unless user.roles.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  index do
    column :email
    #column :encrypted_password
    #column :reset_password_token
    #column :reset_password_sent_at
    column :remember_created_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :last_sign_in_at
    #column :current_sign_in_ip
    #column :last_sign_in_ip
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    #column :authentication_token
    column :roles do | user |
        user.roles.first.name unless user.roles.blank?
    end
    actions
  end
  controller do
    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      binding.pry

      add_roles(@user)
      create!
    end

    def update
      add_roles(resource)
      update!(user_params)
    end

    private
      def add_roles(resource)
        resource.roles = []
        params[:user][:role_ids].each { 
          |r| resource.add_role(Role.find(r).name.downcase!) unless r.blank? 
        }
      end
      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :role_ids => [])
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

It is probably because it does not find the logout path or the current user.
Try to modify your active_admin initializer:

```
config.logout_link_path = :logout_path #Put your logout path here
config.logout_link_method = :delete

config.current_user_method = :current_user
```